# HAproxy request redirecting to multiple backends

Tags: haproxy

I wonder if it is possible to send an HTTP request matching a particular ACL can be redirected to multiple backends in HAProxy. I want to send a copy of the request to another backend as well.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout **teeproxy**

You can forward your requests to multiple machines using teeproxy.

https://github.com/chrislusf/teeproxy

**UPDATE:**

We moved away from teeproxy since its forwarding actively and on high load of traffic, its getting slower We found goreplay as a passive http forwarder and can forward to multiple backends as well.

https://github.com/buger/goreplay